# Two figures are arranged on top and bottom position

Tags: subfloats

I want to arrage two figures in "side-by-side" (left-right). But the out put I got is like this (top-bottom): [image]

My code is here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

This is sample latex code.

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{linux.jpeg}
  \caption{A subfigure}\label{fig1}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{latex.jpeg}
  \caption{A subfigure}\label{fig2}
\end{subfigure}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Obviously, there is a large room to arrange the two figures left and right positions respectively. But latex does this space wasting arrangement. How can I fix it?

Note that I'm using TexLive 2018 installed on Mac.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Does removing the empty line between the subfigures help? I mean something like `...\end{subfigure}
\quad
\begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}...`. An empty line is interpreted as the start as a new paragraph, and starts a new line.

Comment: @marmot Thanks!! I removed the empty line and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll be happy to remove this, which spells out my above comment in more detail.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

This is sample latex code.

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{A subfigure}\label{fig1}
\end{subfigure}
\quad
\begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image-b}
  \caption{A subfigure}\label{fig2}
\end{subfigure}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With inputs by Sigur (`\centering`) and Martin Scharrer (`\hfill`) and the information that `0.4\linewidth` makes the figure `0.4^2=0.16` of the `\textwidth` wide, here is a slightly more advanced proposal:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

This is sample latex code.

\begin{figure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
\centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{A subfigure}\label{fig1}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
\centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image-b}
  \caption{A subfigure}\label{fig2}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe `\centering` in the sub?

Comment: @Sigur I was about to delete this, must be a duplicate. In case you think it should stay, `\centering` is an excellent suggestion, thanks!

Comment: In addition to the `\centering`s inside the `subfigure` environments, changing `\quad` to `\hfill` might be a good idea. This will cause equal distances between the subfigures and the margins.